# RegEx in .htaccess remove duplicate part of URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to be able to remove part of a URL if it is duplicated directly after itself.

For example I have the following URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/foo-bar/
http://www.example.com/foo-bar/foo-bar-1/
http://www.example.com/foo-bar/foo-bar-2/0000-0000/
http://www.example.com/foo-bar/foo-bar-bar/foo/
http://www.example.com/foo-bar/foo-bar-foo/foo/bar/
http://www.example.com/foo-bar/foo-bar-foobar/foo/0000-0000/bar/
```

I would like to remove the first "foo-bar" from the URL only if "foo-bar" appears in the next part of the URL. So I would end up with these URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/foo-bar/
http://www.example.com/foo-bar-1/
http://www.example.com/foo-bar-2/0000-0000/
http://www.example.com/foo-bar-bar/foo/
http://www.example.com/foo-bar-foo/foo/bar/
http://www.example.com/foo-bar-foobar/foo/0000-0000/bar/
```

I used RegExr to test the following RegEx:

```
([a-zA-Z]+[^/]*)\W+\1-
```

That selects all but the first URL as it does not have the duplication of "foo-bar".

I then put that into a RewriteCond and RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([a-zA-Z]+[^/]*)\W+\1-
RewriteRule [a-zA-Z]+[^/]* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And tested it via 'htaccess tester' on the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/foo-bar/foo-bar-foobar/foo/0000-0000/bar/
```

Which got rewritten to:

```
http://www.example.com/foo-bar-foobar/foo/0000-0000/bar/
```

But when I put this code into my .htaccess file and visit the URL it actually redirects to:

```
http://www.example.com/
```

I then went back and looked at the RewriteRule and the RegEx I had used:

```
[a-zA-Z]+[^/]*
```

When I ran this through RegExr I realised that it was selecting alot more than just the first "foo-bar".

I believe this is where I am getting stuck as I am unable to figure out a RegEx that selects just the first "foo-bar". I have tried searching for a solution, I have tried adapting some of the answer people gave to the following questions but to no avail:

[RewriteCond RewriteRule for .htaccess based on URL to a new page, regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043310/rewritecond-rewriterule-for-htaccess-based-on-url-to-a-new-page-regular-expres)

[Regex to find text between second and third slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825979/regex-to-find-text-between-second-and-third-slashes)

I hope I have explained myself well enough. Any questions please ask.

Thank you in advance,
Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/((?=.*?\1).+)$ /$2 [L,R=302,NE]
```